# OAuth in django

Tags: django, oauth

I'm a newbie to the world of django and OAuth .
I have created a django powered demosite running in my localhost and I would like to implement OAuth to access the JSON streaming of my database. Please suggest me any simple  tutorials to get started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be OAuth? Or are you just looking to implement any authentication / authorization mechanism?

Comment: I need OAuth, especially OAuth1.0.

Comment: If I wish to access data from database or service of my web-app the from an outside page(or another django site), it should ask for authentication. There I need to implement OAuth1.0. Both server side and client side I need implement OAuth. how to handle credentials both at server and client side? Any tutorials link is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you use the [Python OAuth library](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2). There is also a [Django oauth library](http://code.larlet.fr/django-oauth/wiki/Home) that migth be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The up to date library is now python-social-auth in its [social-app-django flavor](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) .